# Corrupted record showing in pyspark After Creating data frame from saved json file

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have saved json data from  url into json file named urljson.json in  spark folder. and have performed bellow code  to create data frame on it
by this

```
path="urljson.json/"
testdf1=spark.read.json(path)
testdf1.show()
```

i have got this

[image]

after performing

```
tesdf1.printSchema()
```

bellow format is showing
    root
     |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)

How could i solve this  any guidance will be highly appreciated
i am using spark 2.0

my json data looks like this it is very large i have posted a part of it

```
result:[{"BldgID":"1006AVE ","BldgName":"100-6th Avenue SW (Oddfellows)          ","BldgCity":"Calgary             ","BldgState":"AB ","BldgZip":"T2G 2C4  ","BldgAddress1":"100-6th Avenue Southwest                ","BldgAddress2":"ZZZ None","BldgPhone":"4035439600     ","BldgLandlord":"1006AV","BldgLandlordName":"100-6 TH Avenue SW Inc.                                     ","BldgManager":"AVANDE","BldgManagerName":"Alyssa Van de Vorst           ","BldgManagerType":"Internal","BldgGLA":"34242","BldgEntityID":"1006AVE ","BldgInactive":"N","BldgPropType":"ZZZ None","BldgPropTypeDesc":"ZZZ None","BldgPropSubType":"ZZZ None","BldgPropSubTypeDesc":"ZZZ None","BldgRetailFlag":"N","BldgEntityType":"REIT                     ","BldgCityName":"Calgary             ","BldgDistrictName":"Downtown            ","BldgRegionName":"Western Canada                                    ","BldgAccountantID":"KKAUN     ","BldgAccountantName":"Kendra Kaun                   ","BldgAccountantMgrID":"LVALIANT  ","BldgAccountantMgrName":"Lorretta Valiant                        ","BldgFASBStartDate":"2012-10-24","BldgFASBStartDateStr":"2012-10-24"},{"BldgID":"1007AVE ","BldgName":"100-7th Avenue Southwest-Art Central    ","BldgCity":"Calgary             ","BldgState":"AB ","BldgZip":"T2P 0W4  ","BldgAddress1":"100-7th Avenue Southwest                ","BldgAddress2":"ZZZ None","BldgPhone":"4035439600     ","BldgLandlord":"1007AV","BldgLandlordName":"100-7th Avenue SW (Art Central) Inc.                        ","BldgManager":"LPATER","BldgManagerName":"Lyndsey Paterson              ","BldgManagerType":"Internal","BldgGLA":"27127","BldgEntityID":"1007AVE ","BldgInactive":"N","BldgPropType":"ZZZ None","BldgPropTypeDesc":"ZZZ None","BldgPropSubType":"ZZZ None","BldgPropSubTypeDesc":"ZZZ None","BldgRetailFlag":"N","BldgEntityType":"Property Under Dev't     ","BldgCityName":"Calgary             ","BldgDistrictName":"Downtown            ","BldgRegionName":"Western Canada                                    ","BldgAccountantID":"ABRITTON  ","BldgAccountantName":"Angie Britton                 ","BldgAccountantMgrID":"ZZZ None","BldgAccountantMgrName":"ZZZ None","BldgFASBStartDate":"2011-09-01","BldgFASBStartDateStr":"2011-09-01"},{"BldgID":"100LOMB ","BldgName":"100 Lombard Street                      ","BldgCity":"Toronto             ","BldgState":"ON ","BldgZip":"M5C 1M3  ","BldgAddress1":"100 Lombard Street                      ","BldgAddress2":"ZZZ None","BldgPhone":"4169779002     ","BldgLandlord":"100LOM","BldgLandlordName":"100 Lombard Street Inc.                                     ","BldgManager":"TCHALM","BldgManagerName":"Tiffany Chalmers              ","BldgManagerType":"Internal","BldgGLA":"43697.64","BldgEntityID":"100LOMB ","BldgInactive":"N","BldgPropType":"ZZZ None","BldgPropTypeDesc":"ZZZ None","BldgPropSubType":"ZZZ None","BldgPropSubTypeDesc":"ZZZ None","BldgRetailFlag":"N","BldgEntityType":"REIT                     ","BldgCityName":"Toronto             ","BldgDistrictName":"Queen - Richmond    ","BldgRegionName":"Central Canada                                    ","BldgAccountantID":"MALLORDE  ","BldgAccountantName":"May Ann Allorde               ","BldgAccountantMgrID":"TTSANG    ","BldgAccountantMgrName":"Tony Tsang                              ","BldgFASBStartDate":"2005-11-01","BldgFASBStartDateStr":"2005-11-01"},{"BldgID":"10190104","BldgName":"10190-104th Street NW-The Metals Buildi ","BldgCity":"Edmonton            ","BldgState":"AB ","BldgZip":"T5J 1A7  ","BldgAddress1":"10190-104st Street SW                   ","BldgAddress2":"ZZZ None","BldgPhone":"7804234400     ","BldgLandlord":"10190 ","BldgLandlordName":"10190-104 Street Inc.                                       ","BldgManager":"NEWWES","BldgManagerName":"New West Enterprise Property  ","BldgManagerType":"Third   ","BldgGLA":"20447.75","BldgEntityID":"10190104","BldgInactive":"N","BldgPropType":"ZZZ None","BldgPropTypeDesc":"ZZZ None","BldgPropSubType":"ZZZ None","BldgPropSubTypeDesc":"ZZZ None","BldgRetailFlag":"N","BldgEntityType":"REIT                     ","BldgCityName":"Edmonton            ","BldgDistrictName":"Edmonton            ","BldgRegionName":"Western Canada                                    ","BldgAccountantID":"RYANG     ","BldgAccountantName":"Raymond Yang                  ","BldgAccountantMgrID":"LVALIANT  ","BldgAccountantMgrName":"Lorretta Valiant                        ","BldgFASBStartDate":"2011-08-08","BldgFASBStartDateStr":"2011-08-08"}]
```

Comment: hard to tell without knowing how your json file looks like.

Comment: the problem would be with  the json document not being in a single line and there are new line characters in your json documents.

Comment: Please put your Json File for further details, most of the time the problem is exact as @RajatMishra described !

Comment: i have posted the json data. it was very large set .i have posted part of it

Answer (score 0):

Checking the partial JSON you provided in http://jsonlint.com/ resulted with error: `not a valid JSON`.

Removing the `result:` from the partial JSON and checking in http://jsonlint.com/ resulted with `valid JSON`

Note that in your case, even removing the "result:" from your JSON input, might not result with value spark JSON input as spark supports only limited type of JSON:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets

**JSON Datasets**

Spark SQL can automatically infer the schema of a JSON dataset and load it as a Dataset[Row]. This conversion can be done using SparkSession.read.json() on either an RDD of String, or a JSON file.

Note that the file that is offered as a json file **is not a typical JSON file. Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid JSON object**. For more information, please see JSON Lines text format, also called newline-delimited JSON. As a consequence, a regular multi-line JSON file will most often fail.